# Trigger with definer error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger with a definer and some simple action inside, but doesn't get accepted by mysql and freezes the phpMyadmin without giving an error. Can someone help me to find the mistake

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER log_items after insert on Profiles
FOR EACH ROW
IF USER() LIKE 'admin@%' THEN
     begin    
       INSERT INTO ItemsLog (`record_id`, `record_time`) VALUES (NEW.id, now());
     end; //
END IF;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I have faced this problem, After then I created trigger using phpmyadmin triggers option, right side of the phpmyadmin header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is full trigger code that is accepted by `phpmyadmin`. It was generated when using the sql ide: `SQLyog`.

```
DELIMITER //

USE `testmysql`//

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `log_items`//

CREATE
    DEFINER = 'test'@'localhost'
    TRIGGER `log_items` AFTER INSERT ON `profiles` 
    FOR EACH ROW IF USER() LIKE 'admin@%' THEN
     BEGIN    
       INSERT INTO ItemsLog (`record_id`, `record_time`) VALUES (NEW.id, NOW());
     END; 
END IF;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: The '//' delimiter needed to be after the `END IF` statement.